# No 'the' in "from people who claim"

Tags: definite-article

> Every day we get submissions from **people** who claim that they have solved one of the problems.

Why it is not **the people**? These are the exact people who submit their papers.

Comment: I think the sentence could go either way. You've provided no additional context, so it's hard to say for sure. Depending on where this sentence is in a paragraph, and what else is in the surrounding paragraphs, I might decide it would be better to leave it in, or better to leave it out. I think that one _could_ say **the people** in this sentence, but I don't think one _must_ say **the people.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The noun phrase is **indefinite** because the writer does not expect you to be familiar with these people.  Until they're introduced, they aren't part of the context shared by writer and reader.  They are just now introducing them to you.

Later in the essay, the writer could write "**the** people who claim that they have solved one of the problems".  (Of course, they don't have to refer back to them in this fashion, and are perhaps unlikely to do so.)

Comment: So I can say, for instance, "Today I've got a submission from *a person* who claims that he..." ?

Comment: @Graduate Yes, you can say that.

Answer (score 0):

> Every day we get submissions from people who claim that they have solved one of the problems.

Clearly, the author does not refer to **the particular people** in this case. As they come and claim, they become *the*! Here, people without *the* means people in general and not from a particular group or team.

Comment: Clearly, these **are** particular people – they are the people who claim they have solved a problem. There are times when an article is allowed yet may be omitted; this is one of them. We could say: _Every day we get submissions from **the** people who claim that they have solved one of the problems_, and the sentence would neither be ungrammatical nor change in meaning.